# How to adjust the indentation of the table of Content?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to change the indentation in my memoir class latex document

I tried

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \section
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsection
% \setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsubsection
```

but that yields the error

```
kr.tex|37 error| Undefined control sequence. \cftsecindent  \setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt} % Remove indent for \section
kr.tex|37 error| LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
kr.tex|38 error| Undefined control sequence. \cftsubsecindent  \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt} % Remove indent for \subsection (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def) ) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/p
```

Comment: See `\cftXnumwidth` (page 9).  This sets the width of the section number AND `\leftskip`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `tocloft` package with the `memoir` class which has a similar but not identical way of doing things to the ToC, etc.

```
% memtocprob.tex  SE 606380

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \section
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsection
% \setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsubsection

\end{comment}

\setlength{\cftsectionindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \section
\setlength{\cftsubsectionindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsection


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should probably use regular % to outcomment, new users might not know what the comment env does

Comment: @daleif Thank you for your suggestion to spend even more time on my answers:-) I think that the `comment` environment is valuable to many users. Are you suggesting that answers should only use the very basic TeX macros that probably new users have no clues about? --- GOMFM (Grumpy Old Memory Fading Man)

Comment: No, just noting that we very rarely see the comment env in use. In most editors it's contents are just colored like normal text, so one easily overlook that this is being ignored. I personally prefer marking everything outcommented using %, most editors today have an interface to %-prefix or de-%-prefix a marked region. Also, wasn't the comment env at one point implemented via "writing to file"? This enforcing IO which sliws things down

Comment: @daleif I find the `comment` environment very useful when trying to reply to  questioner's MWE and replacing the OP's code in my answer. I think that there is a difference in code replied as an answer to an OP to that which the original coder would have specified (e.g. I have never, as far as I remember), used the `comment` environment in my stand-alone package/class code.